# Preprocessor problems with VC++6

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

I am porting my single header library to VC++6.

One macro however errors after its expansion.

When I ran `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\Bin\VCVARS32.BAT` and then tried compiling `main.cpp` from the command line calling cl.exe - it worked. I also looked at the preprocessor output with `/EP` and it looked fine.

I created an empty console win32 application and added the single `.cpp` file which includes my header. I haven't added any options to the project because... well... the IDE crashes on some dialogs because it doesn't run well on Windows 7.

The same .cpp file is compilable with mingw and gcc and anything - its simple portable code.

The relevant code is this:

```
#define DOCTEST_STR_CONCAT_IMPL(s1, s2) s1##s2
#define DOCTEST_STR_CONCAT(s1, s2) DOCTEST_STR_CONCAT_IMPL(s1, s2)
#define DOCTEST_ANONYMOUS(x) DOCTEST_STR_CONCAT(x, __LINE__)

#define DOCTEST_SUBCASE(name)                                                                      \
    if(const doctest::detail::Subcase & DOCTEST_ANONYMOUS(DOCTEST_AUTOGEN_SUBCASE_) =              \
            doctest::detail::Subcase(name, __FILE__, __LINE__))

// and in main.cpp:
void f() {
    DOCTEST_SUBCASE("") {}
}
```

and after the preprocessor (from command line with `/EP`) I get this (which is fine and compiles):

```
if(const doctest::detail::Subcase & DOCTEST_AUTOGEN_SUBCASE_20 =
    doctest::detail::Subcase("", "C:\\VC6_TESTS\\doctest\\main.cpp", 20)) {}
```

The error when compiling from within the IDE is this:

```
C:\VC6_TESTS\doctest\main.cpp(20) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier '__LINE__Var'
C:\VC6_TESTS\doctest\main.cpp(20) : error C2072: 'DOCTEST_AUTOGEN_SUBCASE_' : initialization of a function
```

Any ideas why from within the IDE I might be getting bad preprocessor behavior and why it would work from the command line? Or atleast a suggestion what to try...

And please don't tell me not to use VC++6 - I know it's 18 years old but it's a matter of honor to port my library.

**EDIT:**

this turned out to be a compiler bug.

Turning off `Edit and Continue` from the debug info fixed the problem (the `/ZI` command line option)

Here is the minimal example code that reproduces the problem:

```
#define STR_CONCAT_IMPL(s1, s2) s1##s2
#define STR_CONCAT(s1, s2) STR_CONCAT_IMPL(s1, s2)
#define ANONYMOUS(x) STR_CONCAT(x, __LINE__)

struct Subcase
{
    Subcase(const char* name, const char* file, int line) {}
    operator bool() const { return true; }
};

#define MYMACRO(name) if(const Subcase & ANONYMOUS(AUTOGEN_VARIABLE_) = Subcase(name, __FILE__, __LINE__))

int main() {
    MYMACRO("") {}
    return 0;
}
```

and the error when `/ZI` is passed:

```
c:\vc6_tests\doctest\main.cpp(19) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier '__LINE__Var'
c:\vc6_tests\doctest\main.cpp(19) : error C2072: 'AUTOGEN_VARIABLE_' : initialization of a function
```

If anyone has an idea how to trick the preprocessor/compiler into working for the default project config I would be grateful.

Comment: If you increase the build output verbosity and look at it in the IDE you will see how it is ultimately invoking cl.exe and compare the options it is specifying to those you passed manually via the command line.  That would probably a good way to start diagnosing the problem.

Comment: @BrianFairservice holy shit! thanks! I added ```/nologo /MLd /W3 /Gm /GX /ZI /Od /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_MBCS"``` to the command line and now the error is reproduced there too

Comment: I didn't downvote.  Glad that helped though!

Comment: It is not a "bug" but rather a well-known and well-documented limitation of "Edit and Continue" feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution except not to use a compiler from 1998.